# Regex: matching unknown groups that repeat?

Tags: regex, web-crawler

I'm trying to create a generic regex pattern for a crawler, to avoid so called "crawler traps" (links that just add url parameters and refer to the exact same page, which results in tons of useless data). Alot of times, those links just add the same part to a URL over and over again. Here is an example out of a log file:

```
http://examplepage.com/cssms/chrome/cssms/chrome/cssms/pages/browse/cssms/pages/misc/...
```

I can use regular expressions to narrow the scope of the crawler and i would love to have a pattern, that tells the crawler to ignore everything that has repeating parts. Is that possible with a regex?
Thanks in advance for some tips!

JUST TO CLARIFY:

the crawlertraps are not designed to prevent crawling, they are a result of poor web design. All the pages we are crawling explicitly allowed us to do so!

Comment: So if someone's put something in that'll mess with your crawler, it's presumably because they don't want someone crawling their site.

Comment: No it's because the pages are poorly designed...we only crawl pages that explicitly allow us to do so for research/archiving purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already looping through a list of URLs, you could add matching as a condition to skip the current iteration:

```
array = ["/abcd/abcd/abcd/abcd/", "http://examplepage.com/cssms/chrome/cssms/chrome/cssms/pages/browse/cssms/pages/misc/", "http://examplepage/apple/cake/banana/"]

import re
pattern1 = re.compile(r'.*?([^\/\&?]{4,})(?:[\/\&\?])(.*?\1){3,}.*')

for url in array:
    if re.match(pattern1, url):
        print "It matches; skipping this URL"
        continue 
    print url
```

---

Example regex:

`.*?([^\/\&?]{4,})(?:[\/\&\?])(.*?\1){3,}.*`

`([^\/\&?]{4,})` matches and captures sequences of anything, but not containing [/&?], repeated 4 or more times.
`(?:[\/\&\?])` looks for one /,& or ?
`(.*?(?:[\/\&\?])\1){3,}` match anything until [/&?], followed by what we captured, doing all of this 3 or more times.
[demo](https://regex101.com/r/mF3qK5/5)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Actually i wanted to know if it is possible to use a regex to determine IF there is a repeating pattern in a url, without prior knowledge of what this pattern may look like - in your answer it is predefined that a pattern has to consist of 4 letters and repeat exactly 3 times. Interesting for me would be "whatever pattern that repeats more than two times separated by / or & or?"

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see. `{4,}` means "4 or more" (it's greedy), but `{4}` would mean 'exactly'. My 3rd suggestion is more like what you want.

Comment: For some reason backreferences like \1 are not working. I wonder if it's a Python version issue, or something else.

Comment: It turned out that Python, unlike Perl, only considers it a match if the entire string is matched, so I modified the expression to do this. The code I provided should work now and should be enough to set you on your way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a backreference in Python/PERL regexes (and possibly others) to catch a pattern which is repeated:

```
>>> re.search(r"(/.+)\1", "http://examplepage.com/cssms/chrome/cssms/chrome/cssms/pages/browse/cssms/pages/misc/").group(1)
'/cssms/chrome'
```

`\1` references the first match, so `(/.+)\1` means *the same sequence repeated twice in a row*. The leading `/` is just to avoid the regex matching the first single repeating letter (which is the `t` in `http`) and catch repetitions in the path.